# How to customize XML declaration tag in output of XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

My XSLT transforms XML to XML. It outputs the following declaration tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

But I need it to output this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

How?

Answer (score 0):

In the XSLT that you are using, please add the following attribute in the `<xsl:output>` element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" standalone="yes"/>
    ......
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should get the output.